# Debug python program in VSCode remote window with sourced enviroment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ros2

I'm developing a ROS2-application in python and the source code is on the robot and needs a specific environment to run/debug. This environment is setup by sourcing a file, so if I run it manually, it boils down to

```
ssh user@robot
source foo/setup.bash
python3 fancy.py
```

I tried to integrate the source-command as preLaunchTask, but these tasks are executed in their own shell and then a new one (with new environment variables) is started to run the program and I can't find the modules that are added with the source-command.

I assume there is a way to debug in the same terminal in which I ran my preLaunchTasks, but I didn't fine the right config yet.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `envFile` option in `launch.json`?

Comment: That's could be a solution, but I'd have to find out which environment variables are changed by the setup.bash.